# jQuery animation & Flash combined: bad performance, low fps

Tags: jquery, flash, performance, animation, cpu

I'm currently working on a project where I use SWFObject to include a flash header (some fire animation). Also I'm using jQuery for several animations and effects on the page, like Imagesliders and hovering effects.

The problems I got:

- high CPU usage: about 50% on a Intel Q9550
- low frame rates of jQuery animations due to the high CPU usage
- The flash animation seem to stuck when i trigger any jQuery animations or effects

I tried to remove several jQuery animations and simplify the page, but also with only an hover menu, the flash animation stucks and the jQuery animations are laggy when hovering the menu.

The only browsers where my page runs smooth are Chrome and Opera, but only with high CPU usage. FF3&4 and IE7-9 produce bad frame rates all time.

I tried to reduce the jQuery internal fx interval, that seems to help, but the animations were not smooth any more. Am I the only one having this issue, i could not find any other postings here with that topic?!

URL to testsite: http://zend.rollingdevils DOT de

Greetings

---

*Update:*

**Problem solved**

We changes the graphic card of the computer, from a GeForce 8400GS to a 8800GT. After that, the animation run smooth. I never thought that it would be the graphic card ^^

Comment: I'm not sure what "smooth" is supposed to look like, but I get identical behavior out of chrome, ff4, and ie7 (though ie has some css glitches in the menu). CPU usage isn't anywhere near 50% in any case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. We tested the page in the office and also could not find the behaviour described above. So I think this is a local problem on my machine. 
BUT: On a dual-core laptop with 2x2,2GHz, this website takes about 80%! This is a website, no 3d game! I don't know where this comes from...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some websites I did which used both big flash animations and scripts at the same time.

In this case, the best you can do is disable only one script at a time and every time check the result again to see if the overall speed has improved, that way you can find the heavy script.

If you cannot find it this way, try disabling one at a time without reenabling the already disabled ones.

In my websites I had many common jQuery plugins and in the end I realized they were almost all very bad written, with no optimized code.